# Bind to offsetHeight of the <body> from inside a Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to bind to the total (scrolling) height of the body element inside of a Svelte component such that I can calculate the scroll position in an interval between zero and one. [This allows for some cool scroll-triggered CSS animations.](https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/scroll-animation/) The value I'm looking for is stored in the `body.offsetHeight` property.

My first impluse was to bind the property directly using the `<svelte:body>` element.

```html
<script>
    let h;
</script>
<svelte:body bind:offsetHeight={h}></svelte:body>
<span class="debug">{h}</span>
```

In this example `h` will remain undefined even if the window is resized.
[The documentation mentions that the `<svelte:...>` elements are primariliy intended to bind event listeners to them.](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-body) With this in mind, I tried to bind the `resize` event and getting the sizes from there, together with the initial value of `body.offsetHeight` in the `onMount` callback.

```html
<script>
    const handleResize = () => { console.log("yay"); };
</script>
<svelte:body on:resize={handleResize}></svelte:body>
```

Once again, the `handleResize` function is not called when the body is resized.

Is there a way to idiomatically solve this problem in Svelte?
Is it safe to just bind to the body's `resize` event manually in on-mount and updating values from there?

Thanks for taking the time to read this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `on:resize` on the window element itself instead

```
<svelte:window on:resize={handleResize}></svelte:window>
```

Alternatively, you might be able to get the same information of from the window as well? There the bindings work smoothly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the window does not expose any bindings for that info, but event on the window worked, thanks a lot! Feels a bit un-svelt-y tho..

Comment: no, on the window you would have `outerHeight` and `scrollY` I guess ?